# Angular 6 add two classes with ngclass acting out

Tags: angular

I am not sure if this is some sort of a bug, When I try to add classes with ngclass, conditional class. Only the last condition works as expected.

```
   <div class="chat-box">
     [ngClass]="{'chat': chat.type === 'chat', 
    'notification is-danger': chat.type === 'canceled', 
    'notification is-success': chat.type === 'finalized'
                      }"
    </div>
```

The condition for `'notification is-danger': chat.type === 'canceled',` adds just the second class `is-danger`. I have no idea with that is?

While the last conditional in the chain will always work as expected adding `notification is-success`.

Am I doing it wrong or it's just a bug?

[image]

Comment: Stab in the dark, but maybe ngClass is not only applying those class names, but also removing them when the condition is false? So the first doubled-up condition sets both classes, but then the last condition removes the classname they have in common? Perhaps try an alternate method of applying the class names individually and see what that yields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only add/remove single class types. You can't use a string with a space in it.

```
 <div class="chat-box"
      [ngClass]="{'chat': chat.type === 'chat', 
                  'notification': chat.type === 'canceled' || chat.type === 'finalized',
                  'is-danger': chat.type === 'canceled',
                  'is-success': chat.type === 'finalized'}">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh okay. But if that be the case, how is the last condition working? Thanks

Comment: Angular doesn't check the value but the browser is setting the two classes but removes only one.